# Python Pandas: Generate a new column that calculates the subtotal of all the cells above that row in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the seemingly confusing title. The problem shall be really simple but I'm stumped and need some help here.

The data frame that I have now:

```
New_ID  STATE   MEAN
0   1   Lagos   7166.101571
1   2   Rivers  2464.065846
2   3   Oyo     1974.699365
3   4   Akwa    1839.126698
4   5   Kano    1757.642462
```

I want to create a new column that in row i, it will calculate df[:i,'MEAN'].sum()/df['MEAN'].sum()

For example, for data frame:

```
    ID  MEAN
0   1.0 5
1   2.0 10
2   3.0 15
3   4.0 30
4   5.0 40
```

My desired output:

```
     ID MEAN SUBTOTAL
0   1.0 5   0.05
1   2.0 10  0.10
2   3.0 15  0.30
3   4.0 30  0.60
4   5.0 40  1.00
```

I tried

```
df1['SUbTotal'] = df1.loc[:df1['New_ID'], 'MEAN']/df1['MEAN'].sum()
```

but it says:

```
Name: New_ID, dtype: int32' is an invalid key
```

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: Don't say "It doesn't work."  Say "It gives the wrong result and here's why" or "It raises an exception and here is the error message."

Comment: Allow me to edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it, it seems like you're looking for [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df['SUBTOTAL'] = df.MEAN.cumsum() / df.MEAN.sum()

>>> df
    ID  MEAN  SUBTOTAL
0  1.0     5      0.05
1  2.0    10      0.15
2  3.0    15      0.30
3  4.0    30      0.60
4  5.0    40      1.00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Didn't even the function `cumsum` (should I call it a function?). It did work for me.

Comment: Glad to help! I guess it's technically a method, not a function, but I don't think anyone will get too upset if you call it a function :)

Comment: Haha, thanks. Still trying to get my feet wet in Pandas. It almost seems like it has a method for every single thing. Amazing.